Srcset with WordPress featured Image, always returns fallback size
I am trying to use srcset with featured images but it always return the fallback size and I can't workout why.
All the sizes are listed when you inspect it and are correctly sized when you open the links but it will not switch between them.
<section class="pro-act-page-header full-width">
    <?php 
    $header_image = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    if ($header_image) :
        ?>
        <?php
        // Define image sizes based on screen size
        $size_medium = 'medium'; 
        $size_medium_large = 'medium_large'; 
        $size_large = 'large'; 
        $size_full_width_image = 'full_width_image'; 
    
        // Get image source and sizes attributes for different screen sizes
        $srcset_medium = wp_get_attachment_image_url($header_image, $size_medium);
        $srcset_medium_large = wp_get_attachment_image_url($header_image, $size_medium_large);
        $srcset_large = wp_get_attachment_image_url($header_image, $size_large);
    
        // Get alt text and title
        $alt_text = get_post_meta($header_image, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
        $title_text = get_the_title();
        ?>
        <?php // Use the picture element with media queries for responsive images ?>
            <picture>
                <source media="(min-width: 1000px)" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $srcset_large ); ?>">
                <source media="(min-width: 421px)" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $srcset_medium_large ); ?>">
                <source media="(max-width: 420px)" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $srcset_medium ); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url(wp_get_attachment_image_url($header_image, $size_large)); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($alt_text); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($title_text); ?>">
            </picture>
    <?php endif; ?>
</section>

Any help appreciated
